# How to use a webscraper running on an EC2 instance with lambda functions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

I have built a webscraper using python and selenium with geckodriver, it is currently running in an EC2 instance on a crontab schedule.

My issue is it takes more than 5 minutes to finish downloading and I want to use lamda functions to run my scraper but they only allow for 5 minutes of runtime.

So I have a code similar to this.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def start_browser(url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox( executable_path="./geckodriver")
    executable_path="./geckodriver")
    browser.get(url)
    return browser

def log_in(user, pass, user_elem, pass_elem, login_elem, browser):
    user_elem.click().send_keys(user)
    pass_elem.click().send_keys(pass)
    login_elem.click()
    return browser

def nav_to_data(browser, data_elem)
    data_elem.click()
    return browser

def find_data(browser, data_table)
    data_links = data_table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
    return data_links, browser
```

I'm thinking these functions could be ran on lambda functions passing the browser/webdriver instance to each other?

The part I'm struggling with is looping through the data and waiting for all downloads to finish, this would take longer than 5 mins.

Is there anyway around this?

```
def download_data(browser, link)
    link.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    download_elem = browser.find_element_by_id("download_xls_file")
    download_path =    download_elem.click()
    return download_path

# THIS TAKES LONGER THAN 5 mins
download_paths = []
for link in data_links:
    download = download_data(browser, link) # clicks a link to a new page wdownload button and returns path to the .xls file
    download_paths.append(download)

upload_data()
```

Comment: Lambda functions have supported time limits of 15 minutes for several months, FWIW.

Comment: wow I had no idea thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can partition your data and use a recursive lambda to process chunks of your list.
Taking an example from my [blog](https://yorodm.github.io/blog/aws-lambda-tricks/)

```py
def invoke_self_async(data_list, context):
    this_data_list = data_list[0:20] # increase number as needed
    new_event = {
        'data': data_list[20:] # needs to match above number
    }
    boto3.client('lambda').invoke_async(
        FunctionName=context.invoked_function_arn,
        InvokeArgs=json.dumps(new_event)
    )
    my_data = []
    for data in data_list:
        download = download_data(browser, data) # returns path  to .xls file
        my_data.append(download)
    return my_data
```

Comment: Ah my bad I didn't make it so clear in my post, the data in data_list is actually download links for .xls files with my data on, not raw data

Comment: Exactly, if downloading `n` links takes you over 5 minutes you can create `n/x` partitions and download each of them in it's own lambda execution, `invoke_async` guarantees that your lambdas won't wait for each other to finish so the process will be kind of parallel.

Comment: ah I see what you mean , I will try implementing this, thanks a bunch this is great!